# Access JSON using key 0 / 1 instead of name of key

Tags: javascript, jquery, json

I have json that looks more or less like this:

```
{
    "TaskCategoryType": [
        {
            "PK_Column_Value": "C",
            "Column_Description": "Consumables"
        },
        //...
    }
```

I need to retrieve the value of "PK_Column_Value" without knowing the name of the key.

Looping through and getting the record is fine, but I don't want:

```
row.PK_Column_Value
```

in my Javascript as, at runtime, I do not know the name "PK_Column_Value", only that it's the first in the 2 column "pair" per json row.

I tried: row[0] but it gives back undefined.

I want to load a select dropdown box with the value of "PK_Column_Value" and the text of "Description", but I want to send through other json data that has a different column name for the value in JSON.

Comment: In _JavaScript_, the _keys_ of an _Object_ have no order, i.e. you can't guarantee you'll not get `Column_Description` instead

Comment: I know, I don't care about the order, I want to load data from column 1 into value="" for select and column 2 needs to go into the "<option>here</option>. But I don't know what the json contains, only that the first column is the value and the 2nd is the description

Comment: What I'm saying is " the first column is the value and the 2nd is the description" is not true

Comment: @user3036342 - And that's just it, it's an object so there's no guarantee that the first is the value and the second is the description, you can't possibly know.

Comment: You can always use `for (var key in obj) break;` which gives you the first key in `obj`. But as other points out you can never be sure which you will get.

Comment: @NULL - `Object.keys(obj).shift()`, still doesn't matter though ?

Comment: @adeneo do a profiling on that and you see ~10x slower. depending on the objects size. Not to mention that it only works in ECMA 5+

Comment: @NULL there's no guarantee that "the first key" will be `PK_Column_Value`

Comment: @NULL Does XML have the same issue?

Comment: @NULL - `Object.keys` is always slower, it really sucks when it comes to speed, but it looks cooler.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Assuming your object **only** has two keys and you know the **other** key;

```
var o = {
    "PK_Column_Value": "C",
    "Column_Description": "Consumables"
};
```

1. get the keys

   ```
   var keys = [], k;
   for (k in o) keys.push(k);
   ```
2. find *Column_Description*

   ```
   i = keys.indexOf('Column_Description');
   ```
3. get the other key

   ```
   k = keys[1 - i];
   ```

Now

```
k === 'PK_Column_Value';
```

This solves the fact you can't guarantee key order

Comment: The main point of this question is that the name of the field is unknown: `I need to retrieve the value of "PK_Column_Value" without knowing the name of the key.` Whether you directly request the field from the JSON object, or use a string to find the index of the key; both require you to know the key.

Comment: @Flater here I'm assuming he knows there is a key `Column_Description` but not the name of the other key

Comment: If you assume he knows the key, `myObject.Column_Description` is a valid answer, and doesn't require this special loop.

Comment: @Flater if he knows *Column_Description* but not *PK_Column_Value*, how does he get *PK_Column_Value* without something like this?

Comment: I know Column_Description will always be there. This doesn't help as I need <option value="_PK_Column_Value_this_one_changes_and_I_dont_know_the_column_name">Column_Description</option>

Comment: (I was already answering to that. in a new comment now :)) I don't realistically see a use case for this. Why would anyone know *part of the data structure* if he needs to adress *all fields of the data structure*? That's just... wrong from the start. Not saying your answer is wrong, but the situation it caters to is pretty irrelevant.

Comment: @user3036342: Then this is a valid answer and I retract my earlier statement. However, I'm still not sure if this is the best way of handling it, but that's something you have to consider yourself :)

Comment: @Flater I agree that the initial data structure is poorly designed if it encounters this issue

Comment: @user3036342 the purpose of this answer is to find the key we want using the knowledge that the key we don't want to find is called *Column‌​_Description*

Answer (score 2):

The best you can do is loop and check, different browsers can produce different order of objects:

```
for (var i = 0; i < data.TaskCategoryType.length; i++) {
    for (var key in data.TaskCategoryType[i]) {
        console.log(data.TaskCategoryType[i][key]) //Your keys
    }
}
```

Comment: The problem I have with this code is that I can't get the description in the same line, so I'm unable to do $(box).append($("<option></option>").attr("value",row[0]).text(row[1]));

Comment: @user3036342 -- You're right, because Object's can't be accessed via index, the best you can do is loop, get the property name, then assign via the property name you just retrieved.

Comment: So json is pretty much useless then. Why then do anything in the MVC framework (or anything else) if it's so unpredictable? i've looped and chopped data and it always comes through as 0 = value and 1 = description. Never did it suddenly change direction

Comment: @user3036342: Why are you using named fields if you don't expect your frontend to know the name of the fields? You should've used an array (where order IS fixed). It's not an MVC/JSON issue, but a matter of using the right tool for the right job.

Comment: It's all about how you format your data...if this is your use case, as @Flater said, use an array with a fixed order.

Answer (score 1):

The only "clean" way would be to restructure your JSON to contain arrays instead of objects.

```
{
"TaskCategoryType": [
    [
        "C",
        "Consumables"
    ],
    //...
}
```

But personally I'd keep it that way, it makes the code much easier to read and maintain.

Comment: i'm using the MVC framework from MS to generate this from Models, so even if I did take your advice (which is an option I will consider anyway), I'm not 100% sure how to make the model return the json in your format :)

Comment: @user3036342: Make sure your model has a `string[]` property instead of two separate fields with their own name. That will get converted to a json array.